# Editing post using Facebook API returns OAuthException #100

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using Facebook's Graph API for the past couple of months to post updates and new posts on my Facebook page, and it worked perfectly. A couple of days ago the "Edit" feature started returning the error "(OAuthException -#100) (#100) Failed to edit object". 
The Access Token for the page has the following permissions:
user_events, user_posts, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile.
Posting new posts still works, but the Edit feature stopped working.
I'm using C#, My code goes as follows:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
client.AppId = APP_ID;
client.AppSecret = APP_SECRET;

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
paramaters.message = "New update for post";

client.Post("/" + POST_ID, parameters);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug currently being under investigation by Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/749078151890513/

The updating trough api doesn't work from Explorer, nor any facebook SDK(personally I tested Java and Javascript).

The bug was also started a few days ago, and has been set to Assigned on yesterday(January 18th).

As API users we can't do much except for subscribing to the bug and providing more details(if we have any).

**Update:** The fix has been rolled out and it should be now possible to make edits. Facebook bug creator has confirmed it's working, and my tests also showed no problems.